# Using a generic resource for making API calls in Quarkus

Tags: kotlin, resteasy, quarkus

I am creating an application in Kotlin and Quarkus. Now I have created a generic resource which needs to be inherited by my other resources to reduce code redundancy. When my UserResource inherits the GenericResource, I get the following message:

```
It's not possible to add a synthetic constructor with no parameters to the unproxyable bean class
```

I'm quite new to Kotlin and Quarkus, and when I google this specific error message I only get one result of an old bug in Quarkus itself. Below are my UserResource and GenericResource:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/users")
class UserResource(user: UserRepository): GenericResource<User>(user)
```

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
open class GenericResource<T : Any>(
    private var repository: PanacheRepository<T>
    ) {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun findAll() : PanacheQuery<T> = repository.findAll()

    @POST
    @Transactional
    fun add(
        @Valid resource: T
    ) : AddResponse =
        try {
            repository.persist(resource)
            AddSuccess(resource)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            AddFailure(e)
        }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    fun findById(
        @PathParam("id")
        id : UUID
    ) : Uni<T> = repository.find("id", id).firstResult()

    @PUT
    @Transactional
    @Path("/{id}")
    fun update(
        @PathParam("id")
        id : UUID,
        resource: T
    ) : UpdateResponse =
        try {
            repository.persist(resource)
            UpdateSuccess(resource)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            UpdateFailure(e)
        }

    @DELETE
    @Transactional
    @Path("/{id}")
    fun delete(
        @PathParam("id")
        id : UUID
    ) : DeleteResponse =
        try {
            repository.delete("id", id)
            DeleteSuccess("Deletion successful")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            DeleteFailure(e)
        }

}
```

These are the RESTeasy dependencies I'm using:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When I remove the ApplicationScoped annotation from the UserResource, I get the following error message: Could not find constructor for class: com.fortuneapp.backend.application.rest.UserResource

Comment: Which RESTEasy dependencies are you using?

Comment: @geoand, I've updated the qn with the RESTeasy dependencies.

Comment: Using RESTEasy Reactive with Quarkus results in much better Kotlin support. Trying changing `quarkusquarkus-resteasy*` with `quarkus-resteasy-reactive*` and `quarkus-rest-client` with `quarkus-rest-client-reactive*`

Comment: I've added the reactive dependencies, and rewritten some code to make it reactive. Unfortunately I'm still getting an error: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: It's not possible to add a synthetic constructor with no parameters to the unproxyable bean class: com.fortuneapp.backend.application.rest.UserResource. I've updated my code in the qn with the reactive code.

Comment: Did you try making `UserResource` open as well?